# $P(x) = x^3 – ax^2 + bx + c$. has integral roots such that $P(6) = 3$ then sum of all possible values of $a$ is

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots

> Consider the cubic polynomial $P(x) = x^3 – ax^2 + bx + c$. If the equation $P(x) = 0$ has integral roots such that $P(6) = 3$ then sum of all possible values of $a$ is

**My try**  Let $\eta$ be the root of $P(x)=0$ then by rational root theorem $\eta|c$ also $$P(6)=3\Rightarrow 216-36a+6b+c=3$$
$$\Rightarrow 3|c$$
What do i do next?

Please provide hints rather than complete solutions (it helps me)

Comment: An idea : Write $P(x)=(x-u)(x-v)(x-w)$ with integral $u,v,w$. Then $(6-u)(6-v)(6-w)=3$. Hence, as the divisors of $3$ are...

Comment: @Kelenner nice idea i will try if possible will self answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very much thanks to @kelenner to put me in the right direction:

we have $$(6-u)(6-v)(6-w)=3$$
we see that for $xyz=3$ we can heve the following unordered  pairs $$(6-u,6-v,6-w)=(1,1,3),(1,-1,-3),(-1,-1,3)$$
which means the unorederd triplet can take $$(u,v,w)=(5,5,3),(5,7,9),(7,7,3)$$
Thus by vieta $$a=u+v+w=13,17,21$$